# Compactness in a short exact sequence of topological groups

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, exact-sequence

Suppose $H,G,K$ are abelian Hausdorff topological groups and $0\to H\overset{\alpha}\to G\overset{\beta}\to K\to 0$ an exact sequence of continuous homomorphisms. 
If $H$ and $K$ are compact, can we conclude that $G$ is compact too? 
(I know that the answer is yes if $\beta$ is open or closed, but can we drop this hypothesis?)

Comment: Not sure, but if you can somehow prove that $G$ is $\sigma$-compact, then $\beta$ would be open, and you'd be done.

Comment: I havn't thought about it completely, but what about $H=0$,$G=S^1$ with the discrete topology,K=$S^1$ with the regular topology and $\beta$ the identity?

Comment: Of course this is a counterexample! Please post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about $H=0$, $G=S^1$ with the discrete topology, $K=S^1$ with the regular topology and $\beta$ the identity?